# TermService not working

Tags: windows, rdp, rpc, mstsc

my company stumbled upon this issue last week and it took us a while to find a solution. We didn't find anything similar on the net so I figured I might as well try to help others.

We had a Win2012 server where TermService (**Remote Desktop Service** aka the service responsible to allow for MSTSC/RCP connections) **stopped working suddenly**.

The service would start correctly, not displaying any error message but would simply not start listening on the configured port.

Well it happens that our issue was not termservice itself but **the registry configuration of the RPC which we destroyed**.

Replacing the configuration from a valid config from a backup and restarting the box fixed the problem.

Hope this helps someone.